# The whole content widget is forcefully hidden when some parts are not visible in the editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

I am using view zone with content widget combination to show custom widgets below the code in the editor. As I can see, the visibility style is [forcefully set to hidden](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/contentWidgets/contentWidgets.ts#L434) if the bounds of the widget are not fully visible in the editor. Is there a way to disable this behavior? Maybe the view zone with content widget combination is not the correct approach at all... If that is the case, could someone please advise? I got the idea from code lens.

Comment: post your code in the question rather than a link to a repo

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to work around it with a `MutationObserver`. Something like this did the trick for me:

```
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations: MutationRecord[], observer: MutationObserver) => {
    mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        if (mutation.attributeName && mutation.attributeName === 'style') {
            if (contentWidget.style.visibility === 'hidden') {
                contentWidget.style.visibility = 'inherit';
            }
        }
    })
});

observer.observe(contentWidget, {
    attributes: true
});
```